# Inline comments indentation in webstorm

Tags: webstorm

I'm just starting with Webstorm and the inline comments with CTRL+/ make me afraid.

```
        // Retrieve the user
//      User.findOneById(player_id).done(function(err, user) {
//        player = user;
//        log('Player '+player.name+' played hole `'+playedHole+'`');
//      });
```

How I can get this ?

```
        // Retrieve the user
        // User.findOneById(player_id).done(function(err, user) {
        //   player = user;
        //   log('Player '+player.name+' played hole `'+playedHole+'`');
        // });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Currently you cannot:** http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2189

But when you reformat the code it can realign comments (with right option activated: Code Style | JavaScript | Wrapping and Braces | Keep when reformatting | Comment at first column) -- it will re-indent commented lines to the same indent as previous line.